# Trying to auto-generate SKUs in Google Sheets using prefix and sequence number but it breaks when sheet is sorted

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I want to automatically generate unique, incremented ids (SKUs) for products in my inventory using Google Sheets. These SKUs should be immutable and not change when the sheet is sorted. This screenshot shows my flawed attempt to do this:

[image]

The formula I have for column A is:

`=if($B2<>"",$B2 & TEXT(COUNTIF($B$2:$B2,$B2),"-0000"),"")`

That formula appears to give the desired result. However, if I sort by the values in Column C, SKUs become associated with different Item Names, which is a problem. How can I modify the spreadsheet to get immutable, auto-generated SKUs?

[image]

**Update:**

- I would like to be able to add additional rows/SKUs to the sheet over
  time
- Here is a [link to the sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aP2JPOpUcF-qHtRwKWKWXt5yl8HyDRZ4smWWTaL9U4Y/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please share a link to your sample spreadsheet. Also, please be clear about whether you're trying to assign SKUs to a ***complete*** list of items, or to a list that may have more items added to it or deleted from it over time. If its already a complete list (or if the timestamp when each item is added can be included at the time of entry), formulas can handle the job. If not, you'll need to use script.

Comment: I plan to keep adding items to the sheet. Here is the link (I'll put it in the question too.) https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aP2JPOpUcF-qHtRwKWKWXt5yl8HyDRZ4smWWTaL9U4Y/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm not clear on what you mean by "I plan to keep items to the sheet." Do you mean that the item list is complete and that it will not have items added to or deleted from it in the future?

Comment: Typo "keep adding"

Comment: And will your real-world application *only* be including the three columns of data shown in your post? Or will there be additional columns that need to be sorted along with these three? If the latter, will all of those columns be static data; or will some/all be flexible data (e.g., notes, inventory counts, etc.)? Every detail matters. Otherwise, one of the volunteer contributors here may work up something that addresses your *posted* need, but not your *actual* needs.

Comment: There are additional columns in the actual spreadsheet, some of which are static (but editable) and others are based on simple formulas.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239002/discussion-between-michael-swarts-and-erik-tyler).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added a sheet ("InventoryMaster(Unsorted") to your spreadsheet.

This sheet would be used to add your prefixes and items *only*. Once added, you would never sort, insert rows, delete rows or items, etc. Just keep adding the next prefix and item into the next open row, in Col B and Col C. Col A has a formula that will create the static SKUs from that unchanging and ordered information. (I've hidden that formula-containing Col A, so that you only have to enter the manual data and don't have to worry about accidentally overwriting the formula or its results. It's still there at all times, serving its purpose in the background.)

*Then*, other sheets (see my added "Erik Help" sheet) can reference that "immutable" list, giving you the ability to sort without losing SKU connection.

Here is the A1 formula from the 'InventoryMaster(Unsorted)' sheet:

`=ArrayFormula({"SKU";IF(B2:B="",,B2:B&TEXT(COUNTIFS(B2:B,B2:B,ROW(B2:B),"<="&ROW(B2:B)),"-0000"))})`

And here is the SKU-assigning formula from A1 of the "Erik Help" sheet:

`=ArrayFormula({"SKU";IF(B2:B="",,VLOOKUP(B2:B&C2:C,{'InventoryMaster(Unsorted)'!B2:B&'InventoryMaster(Unsorted)'!C2:C,'InventoryMaster(Unsorted)'!A2:A},2,FALSE))})`